# Not return row from table when use the case when condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a basic question.
I want to return data from my table when the condition is true but when it is not I got the null row, but I don't want that.

This is my example:

```
 select case when coalesce(var, '') != '' then (select id from user) end
```

when var is not '' I got data, bat, when is not I, got `null`

[image]

Comment: I'm not even sure this query would run.  To which table does the column `var` belong?

Comment: I do not want to execute my `select id from user` when is `coalesce(var, '') != ''`
Now is better to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter with a `WHERE` condition:

```
select id from "user"
where coalesce(var, '') = '';
```

Comment: I do not want to execute `select id from "user"`  when is `coalesce(var, '') != ''`. I think I am not understandable.

Comment: Then replace the `!=` with `=`. If `var` is a constant, then the query will never be executed.

Comment: Thanks this is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply just need to filter out your `NULL`s returned in a `where` clause:

```
select coalesce(var, id)
from user
where coalesce(var, id) is not null
```

`coalesce` returns the first non-null value in a list of fields. When neither condition is met a `NULL` row will be returned and the `where` clause will filter those out.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for:

```
select id
from "user"
where var <> '';
```

You don't need to handle `NULL`s as a special case, because `<>` will not return any rows when `var` is `NULL`.